# How to config Codeigniter 4 using mssql connection?

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to config CI4 connect using SQL Server.
if in CI3

```
$db['dbsqlsrv'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'port' => '1433',
 'username' => 'sa',
 'password' => 'example',
 'database' => 'example',
 'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

How config this option to work in CI4. Because when i update .env database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi to database.default.DBDriver = Mssql can't work.

Comment: As of this comment the mssql driver hasn't been converted from CI3 to the changes the Devs made in CI4.  https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

In CI4 you can use `'DBDriver' => 'SQLSRV'` as mentioned in the following CI4 documentation URL

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

The full block would be as follow

```
public $default = [
'DSN'      => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'YOUR_USER',
'password' => 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
'database' => 'DATABASE_NAME',
'DBDriver' => 'SQLSRV',
'DBPrefix' => '',
'pConnect' => false,
'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cacheOn'  => false,
'cacheDir' => '',
'charset'  => 'utf8',
'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swapPre'  => '',
'encrypt'  => false,
'compress' => false,
'strictOn' => false,
'failover' => [],
'port'     => 1433
```

];

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

to use mysql database in codeigniter 4 you should keep the For mysql you should keep the following changes.
in .env file

```
database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

in app/Config/Database.php

```
public $default = [
...
DBDriver=>'MySQLi',
...
];
```

Answer (score -1):

**CodeIgniter 4**

In app >> config >> Database.php

Check the **$defaultGroup** value

```
public $defaultGroup = 'default';

public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'YOUR_USER',
    'password' => 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
    'database' => 'DATABASE_NAME',
    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3308,
];
```